# Making UITableView drop down with stackview

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uistackview

I am trying to achieve a `UITableView` drop down when I click on a button. Initially the `tableView` should be hidden, and when user presses button, it should drop down. I have been trying to achieve this with a `UIStackView` but to no success. Maybe I am doing it wrong or maybe there is another approach do do this.

```
let stackView = UIStackView()
var btn: UIButton!
var myTableView = UITableView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myTableView.delegate = self
    myTableView.dataSource = self
    myTableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 1))
    myTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200)
    myTableView.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width/2, y: self.view.frame.height/2)
    myTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false

    btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50))
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
    btn.setTitle("DropDownMenu", for: UIControlState.normal)
    btn.titleLabel?.textColor = .white
    btn.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    btn.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width/2, y: myTableView.center.y - myTableView.frame.height/2 - btn.frame.height/2)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnPressed), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical
    stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.equalSpacing
    stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.center
    stackView.spacing = 16.0
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.view.addSubview(btn)
    stackView.addSubview(myTableView)
    self.view.addSubview(stackView)

}

@objc func btnPressed() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
        self.myTableView.isHidden = !self.myTableView.isHidden
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = "This is cell " + indexPath.row.description
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = .black
    return cell
}
```

I can get the `tableView` to disappear but with no animations. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try not using the `UIView.animate` block?

Comment: @jjatie Yes, same behaviour regardless.

Comment: I've done the exact same thing before. The only difference is I don't call `UIView.animate` and I don't set `stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`. Then in storyboard (or code), make sure that you have appropriate constraints. In my experience, `UIStackView` requires autolayout

Comment: @jjatie Yes well what would the appropriate constraint be?

Comment: Usually just edge constraints on your stack view. It really depends on what you want your layout to be

Comment: @jjatie Okey, I am quite new to auto-layout and Im trying to do it programmatically so I have to figure it all out first I guess. My layout is nothing complex though, is there any guide/tutorial you can point me to?

Comment: Try Mysteries of Autolayout parts 1 and 2 from WWDC

Answer (score 0):

The approach I ended up taking was not going via a `UIStackView` but insead simply having a button that animates the `tableView`'s frame. The frame is initially set to the width of the screen and a height of 0. When user presses button, I set the height.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.menuTable.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (sender.center.y + sender.frame.height/2), width: self.view.frame.width, height: yourHeight)
        })
```